# Unable to create a loop using usedrange property

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

The worksheet I'm working with has two cells filled in, one with `Total` and the other with `value`. They are next to each other. My goal is to catch the `Total` and print it's `value`. As I do not wish to know their specific cell address so I created a loop and did the job. I did it using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)`. Now, I would like to do the same using `.UsedRange`.

My question is: how can I do the same (creating the loop) using `.UsedRange`.

This is I have tried with (working one):

```
Sub FindTotalValue()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    'Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'For Each cel In rng.Row

    For Each cel In Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If InStr(cel.Value, "Total") > 0 Then MsgBox cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next cel
End Sub
```

As I know nothing about creating a loop using `.usedrange` method, I just commented them out within the script.

Comment: you do know that there is a [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) function in excel right?

Comment: Why not just use named ranges here?

Comment: It didn't come to my mind @Banana. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub FindTotalValue()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(cel.Value, "Total") > 0 Then MsgBox cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next cel
End Sub
```

It assumes that the cell containing "Total" is a constant, not a formula:

[image]

You should also investigate using *Find()* rather than a loop.

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Banana's suggestion:

```
Sub FindTotalValue()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(cel.Value, "Total") > 0 Then
            MsgBox cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

To use *Find()*:

```
Sub FindTotalValueQuickly()
    MsgBox Cells.Find(what:="Total", lookat:=xlPart).Offset(0, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: you should add an `Exit For` statement, once total is found there is no need to continue with the loop

Comment: @Banana  Thank you very much! I added an **EDIT**

Comment: This sort of answer should instantly be accepted. I was away so sorry for the delay. A little question on the usage of `SpecialCells(2)`. Why 2? Thanks in advance @Gary's Student.

Comment: @Topto have a look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)

Comment: @Topto  *SpecialCells(2)* are all the **constants** on the worksheet..........if the "Total" cell was a formula cell then *SpecialCells(-4123)* should be used.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Much appreciated.